# Android music player that supports per-album resume

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I listen to a lot of audiobooks, podcasts, lectures, etc. on my Android phone, all saved in the internal memory and often split between multiple files.

My problem: I find it annoying that if I'm listening to something and I want to switch to something else (say: a book I'm halfway through), I have to manually "seek" to the track/position I was at the last time I listened to that particular book (or whatever).

So what I need is a music player that automatically remembers, for each album, at which track I was when I last listened to that album. When I tell it to play that particular album the player should then automatically start playing the album from the last position I was listening to.

Bonus feature: would be great if it remembered not only the track, but the position in the track as well, and resume from the exact same point I was listening to the last time.

Comment: Very similar to the other question; I've improved the other question a touch to hopefully help drive answers to it.